# WPF Frame Inside StackPanel not firing events

Tags: wpf, events, wpf-controls

I dynamically create a frame and add it to the children of the stackpanel.   The mouse events were working fine, but have stopped for some reason.  Any help is appreciated.  Here's where I create them:

```
Frame newFrame = new Frame();
Page current = Globals.Static.GetCurrentProcess() as Page;
current.Width = 1199;   // Doing this here forces the scaletransform to shrink entire app -- must be done on the page
newFrame.Content = current;
newFrame.Width = 384;
newFrame.Height = 288;  // Doing this here will limit the shrunk app's height -- must be done on the frame
newFrame.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseButtonEventHandler(newFrame_MouseDoubleClick);
newFrame.Name = current.Title + "_Frame";
this.stackRunning.Children.Add(newFrame);

Separator newSeparator = new Separator();
newSeparator.Name = current.Title + "_Separator";
this.stackRunning.Children.Add(newSeparator);
```

`stackRunning` is an empty `StackPanel` in the main window.  In the event handler, I just create a variable and I put a stop on it.  It never fires.

Answer (score 2):

Your frame might not be hit-able because it has not background. Have you tried setting the background?

Comment: Yes, i set the background to a solid color... still no go.

Comment: May not have been the OP's problem but was definitely mine. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Your mouse clicks might be swallowed by child-elements, using `PreviewMouseDoubleClick` instead might help.

Comment: I've tried MouseDown, PreviewMouseDown & PreviewMouseDoubleClick... none of them fire.  It's strange ... this was working and suddenly stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why.  I added some new overloaded scrollbar code for the scrollviewer and it was catching stuff.  Thanks guys.

Comment: Make sure next time you ask a question to show code that actually contains the error. That will make it easier for us to help you and will make the question more interesting for others who are looking for help in a similar situation. Thanks.